# Drupal project isn't installing in LAMP server in ubuntu

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

My client had a Drupal project (it isn't a template), she wanted me to install it and improve the quality of the project.
In `sites/default/settings.php`, I added the following:

```
 $databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'csp',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '<password>',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '3306',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Then I created a DB, CSP in MySql.
When I go to `http://localhost/csp-v1/install.php`, then I get the following screen:
[image: img]
I'm unable to install that project. How can I fix it?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install continue from step 4. If you already did that please update your question.

Comment: @melvin: I've updated the question, can you check it?

Comment: Are you installing the standard profile of panopoly ? and if yes what version?

Comment: @melvin: It is panopoly 1.21

Comment: By chance i installed panopoly yesterday and i had no problem with the standard profile. But you might take a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/2183937 and implement the patch from comment 20 to see if that fixes it for you. But seems to be a panoply bug

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the settings.php
copy the default.settings.phph end rename it as settings.php
Give the right to write in the new settings.php then install again and provide your database information on the install form.